# A Question from Mathematical circles Book

Tags: graph-theory

A chessboard has the form of a cross, obtained from 4x4 chessboard by deleting the corner squares (see figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO0eO.jpg). Can a knight travel around this board, pass through each square exactly once, and end on the same square he starts on?

I tried to solve the problem by making a graph (see figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok5DP.jpg) and then transformed this graph for better visualization (see figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MvVI.jpg) but still the answer I am getting is such a path is not possible, while in solutions it is given such a path is possible and can be easily constructed. (see figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq79e.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if I understood the problem correctly, but this could be a solution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Fze.jpg

Comment: I cant understand what those numbers imply

Comment: The knight starts at square 1, then goes to 2 and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Numbering the squares 1-12, a sequence is
$$1,6,8,2,10,4,12,7,5,11,3,9,1$$
The way I found it was first to notice that each of the four center squares can only be reached by two other squares, so any complete path through 4, say, must contain the sequence $10,4,12$ or $12,4,10$. Similarly, the groupings have to include
$$10,4,12$$
$$7, 5, 11$$
$$2, 8, 6$$ and
$$1,9,3$$
From there it was simply connecting the end points of the four segments to find a path.

Comment: if you check the figure i have added for the given chess board, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO0eO.jpg you can clearly see that a knight cannot move from 1 to 6.

Comment: @CaesarJ_889 Yes it can.

Comment: it can move from 6 to 1 but not from 1 to 6, if you follow chess rules (here the corners have been removed)

Comment: Then you need to explain what rules you are using, because in the chess I know, a knight can move 2 squares over and then 1 square at right angles, in any direction.  In the middle of a regular chessboard, a knight has 8 spots it can move to.

Answer (score 1):

According to chess rules, a knight can move two squares vertically and one square horizontally, or two squares horizontally and one square vertically. That is enough to conclude the possibility of movement of a knight from $6$ to $1$ and $1$ to $6$ in image $1$. A graph is constructed using possible movements of a knight from all points.
Marking of points and graph construction.  [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwIby.jpg)

Image $2$ is to visualize the graph better, possible movement can start from $8$, and can follow the path via $2,3,9,1,7,5,11,10,4,12,6$, and then can come back to starting point $8$. [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2ZcP.jpg)